# Can one call AWS Pinpoint validate via SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-pinpoint

According to the Amazon PinPoint API, it provides a REST endpoint to validate phone numbers. Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/apireference/rest-api-phone-number-validate.html

Can anyone please confirm if this feature is available within the Java AWS SDK?  Could it be this API, being new, is only available via REST?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you update your AWS Java SDK (in case if you haven't done it already). 
Phone number validate feature is present in the Java sdk as well.

Refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/pinpoint/model/NumberValidateRequest.html